how to say the adjectival "one-time" / "non-recurrent" in Latin
say to say "one-time expense" i.e., not-regular.
I hoped we could find a conversion of the adverb semel into an adjective.
for recurrent I thought frequens could work as well as assiduus. Though infrequens clearly does not quite convey the same color as "one-time"/"non-recurrent", and searching for "non as(d)siduus" in PHI did not yield the results I hoped for.
It looks like i am missing the word here to express this (either positively or on the negative).

The word unicus comes to mind, and L&S describes the main meaning as "one and no more, only, sole, single".
It does not refer specifically to time, though, so you need some recasting to use it to convey the idea of "one-time".
A "one-time dinner" could well be simply cena unica, especially if an expectation of or a comparison to a recurring dinner is implied by the context.
The words singuli and singularis, though also related to "one", mean more "one at a time" than "just once".
Singularis does also have the sense of "unique", but the risk of confusion is too high.
Perhaps solus points more in the same direction as unicus, but is not quite as good a fit.

Forgot about unicus, thanks!. I was thinking eximius but didn't like it.

Even unus would work, though unicus was where my first thoughts went to as well.
